# Accessing only current record in index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model named "Profile".

I want to show the Profile based on the current_user.id only, so when the user goes to /profiles, it will "show" the profile instead of listing down the profile.

Profile has user_id column in the model.

The controller for Profile is currently set to:

```
class ProfileController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @profiles = Profile.where(user_id:current_user.id)
  end

  def show
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
  end
```

I have looked at Active Records query methods and i couldn't find a suitable answer for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources) to read about singular resources. Incidentally, it talks about your specific use case. Assuming you have the current_user and a has_one relationship setup, you could then just call @profile = current_user.profile

To be more verbose, if you add resource :profile to your routes file, you can just link to profile_path. This will route to the show action. Simply ensure current_user is set and retrieve the profile leveraging the has_one relationship.

Hope this helps.